# Which browsers handle client-side compression of requests such as POST'ed formdata?

Tags: apache, http, browsers

Which browsers handle **client-side compression** of requests, such as "multipart/form-data" transmitted by the client to the server via HTTP POST ?

The HTTP server I am trying to get this working with is Apache with the `mod_deflate` and `mod_gzip` modules, which understand `Content-Encoding: deflate` and `Content-Encoding: gzip` headers in the POST requests.

My "multipart/form-data" sent to the server usually contains large PDF files.

Comment: See also on [so]: [Compressing HTTP Post Data sent from browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13031968/compressing-http-post-data-sent-from-browser)

Comment: @Stephen:  Thanks, I already saw it it.  I was hoping something has changed during these 7 years, as that question was from 2012.  Also, see this question:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20507007/http-request-compression